# loading gltf file configuration error in nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, three.js, next.js, gltf

I am trying to load a gltf file in a nextjs application.It works fine when i set up a new react application project.But its not working when i try to run it with nextjs application on my current project.This is how i configured next.js:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require('next-images');

    const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
    module.exports = withPlugins([
        [withCSS, { cssModules: true  }],
        [withImages],
    ], {
        serverRuntimeConfig: {   serverRuntimeConfigValue: 'test server'  },
        // publicRuntimeConfig: {   publicRuntimeConfigValue: {apiUrl:'http://127.0.0.1:5000'} },
        publicRuntimeConfig: {   publicRuntimeConfigValue: {apiUrl:process.env.apiUrl.trim()} },
        webpack: (config, options) => {   return config;   },exportTrailingSlash: true
    });
```

I am getting this error in nextjs when i try to show the model:

```
 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| {
>   "asset": {
|     "version": "2.0",
|     "generator": "Sketchup glTF Exporter v1.2.6 by Centaur"
```

I am importing the file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import fileGlb from './villa.gltf' // GLTF FILE
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide your webpack config?

Comment: on my first block code isn't there a setup for webpack config.I dont have any other webpack config file.I am new on this nextjs webpack setup.